# Apply a list of functions to an argument inside Piecewise

Tags: piecewise

I would like use `Through`, or some other method, to apply a list of functions to the same argument inside `Piecewise`. For example, for known functions `f[x_],g[x_],h[x_],...`

```
Through[Piecewise[{{1, m > 0}}, {f,g,h,...}[x]], List]
```

gives

> ```
> Piecewise[{{1, m > 0}}, {f,g,h,...}[x]]
> ```

but I would like to get

> ```
> Piecewise[{{1, m > 0}}, {f[x],g[x],h[x],...}]
> ```

How can I get `{f,g,h,...}[x]` to evaluate inside `Piecewise`?

Comment: Why are you using `{f}[2]` rather than just `f[2]`? `Piecewise[{{1,m>0}},f[2]]` works.

Comment: I was taking the simplest example. In reality, I have multiple functions `{f,g,h,...}[x]` and I would like `{f[x],g[x],h[x],...}` to appear inside `Piecewise`.

Comment: I have modified the question in response to Bob Hanlon's comment. Thanks, Bob.

Comment: `Piecewise[{{1, m > 0}}, {f, g, h}[x]] /. list_List[x] :> Through[list[x]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pw = Piecewise[{{1, m > 0}}, {f, g, h}@x];

MapAt[Through, pw, -1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]